# Java EE Persistence WELD-001408 when deploying on wildfly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jboss, wildfly

I have a problem, when I want to deploy my application on wildfly.

This is my persistence:

```
<persistence-unit name="jws" transaction-type="JTA">
    <class>lv.lavloz.merrill.generator.v1.model.ID</class>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MySQL/JWSDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

The connection url for the jndi `java:jboss/datasources/MySQL/JWSDS` is `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db`.

And this is the ejb :

```
@Stateless
public class GeneratorBean {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "jws")
    private EntityManager em;
...
}
```

When I want to deploy my application to wildfly, I get the error message

```
java.lang.Exception: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"jws_ear.ear\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"jws_ear.ear\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type ParamConverterFactory with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject public org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.MultivaluedParameterExtractorFactory(ParamConverterFactory)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.MultivaluedParameterExtractorFactory.<init>(MultivaluedParameterExtractorFactory.java:0)
WELD-001474: Class org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.ParamConverterFactory is on the classpath, but was ignored because a class it references was not found: org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator from [Module \"deployment.jws_ear.ear:main\" from Service Module Loader].
"}}
```

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem to be related to JPA at all.

Your error message referring to `org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal` indicates that your application has a dependency on Jersey.

Are you trying to port an application from GlassFish to WildFly? If so, you should eliminate all dependencies on Jersey and only use the JAX-RS APIs, or WildFly's JAX-RS implementation RESTEasy.

Jersey is not contained in WildFly.